# Finite Series Calculation

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am a totally math newbie.  I would like to calculate the series below,

$1 + 1.05 + 1.1025 + 1.157625 + \ldots$

So every new element is the 5% more of the previous one.

Comment: If it's finite we would need to know how many terms there are or the last term to calculate

Comment: let's say 30 terms

Comment: Look into Geometric series: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number 5% larger than $x$ is $1.05x$, so the terms of your series is $1.05^n$. Such a series is called a geometric series, and the sum of a number of terms from such a series is given by the "formula":
$$
\frac{\text{last term not included}-\text{first term}}{\text{ratio}-1}
$$
or if we fill in your values:
$$
\frac{1.05^{29+1}-1}{1.05-1}
$$
(29 because the first term is $1.05^0$)
If we put that into a calculator (or computer) we get the value $66.438847503$.

Comment: You formula is not right.

Comment: As is mentioned after Joshua Farrell's answer, the correct formula would be $$\frac{\text{last term}\cdot\text{ratio}-\text{first term}}{\text{ratio}-1}$$

Comment: Corrected (I don't know why this comment wasn't posted sooner).